# Setting ContentType for default entries in Office Open XML package's [Content_Types].xml

Tags: c#, ms-office, openxml

I've recently inherited some legacy code, to give you an idea of my familiarity with this subject matter.

I have a C# application that creates an Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx) by constructing a zip package containing the necessary XML files.  The application manually creates the [Content_Types].xml file, and zips the package using Visual J#.  I'm trying to get rid of our dependence on Visual J# by using System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage.

I can construct the zip package correctly, with all the necessary files.  When I add package parts, I set their content type string, which is reflected in [Content_Types].xml.  However, [Content_Types].xml is missing a few necessary entries, which Excel interprets as a corrupted file.

For instance, in a correct content types file, there is a default entry named "rels":

```
<Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
```

In my zip package, the rels entry has an empty string for the ContentType attribute.  Since rels isn't a part in the package, I don't know how to set its ContentType.  Is there a way to do this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the parts "xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels" and "xl/worksheets/_rels/datatable.xml.rels" in the Excel document's ZipPackage, set their ContentType strings to "application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml".

This sets the ContentType of the Relationships Part, according to ISO/IEC 29500-2, Annex F.